# Soved -- Is there a way of making form method="get" output only certain values in the url?

Tags: html, forms, methods, get

Solved - I got pointed out that I should not hide values from the URL for shareability and what else.

I have this piece of code:

```
<form name="service" method="get" action="service.php"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $data[0]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $data[1]; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="description" value="<?php echo $data[2]; ?>">
    <section class="4u" style="float: left; margin-bottom: 50px;">
        <header>
            <h2><?php echo $data[0]; ?></h2>
        </header>
        <span class="pennant"><span class="fa fa-street-view"></span></span>
        <p>Base price: <?php echo $data[1]; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $data[2]; ?></p>
        <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()" class="button button-style1">More info</a>
</section>
</form>
```

The form method, as stated in the title, is "GET", and that shows all values that are set inside the form.

Is there a way of only showing, for example, the value of this input -

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $data[0]; ?>">
```

- so it only shows in the url www.website.com/page?name=(value)

Is it even possible?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to hide *some* data from the URL?

Comment: @Quentin the url currently looks like this - localhost/computek/servico.php?nome=Aconselhamento&preco=5.00&descricao=Recomenda%E7%F5es+de+pe%E7as+para+upgrades+ou+melhoria+de+desempenho.
and all information besides nome=Aconselhamento would be unnecessary, and I'd like to hide it if possible

Comment: And what is wrong with it looking like that?

Comment: all information besides nome=Aconselhamento would be unnecessary, and I'd like to hide it if possible, for "aesthetic" purposes
If not, I'll just go back to POST.

Comment: If the information isn't necessary, why are you sending it to the server in the first place? Stop trying to make aesthetically pleasing URLs. They are tools. Most people won't notice if they are pretty and by switching to POST you'll screw up the ability of people to link to pages and use the back button without a "Sure you want to repost this form?" prompt.

Comment: I guess you're right. Thanks for the guidance :)

Comment: @Quentin could you enlighten me once more?  Is there a way of preventing the change of the url of affecting the values on the page?  I use 2 of the values that show up on the url to change a dynamic page, and if I write something on the page it changes everything that uses said value. - I use $name=$_GET['name'] (comes from the form of the previous page)

Answer (score -1):

Normally for forms we use the post method but if you want to show on the url only one value just "?" following by the name of the field you want to output.